# XQuery expression. Something about ordering

Tags: xquery

I have to order and then print out parts of a text. I've tried some expressions and finally became the code that help me, but I think it isn't really good.

I will post a part of the text and then the code that I've made.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipes>
  <recipe>
    <title>Beef Parmesan with Garlic Angel Hair Pasta</title>
    <ingredient name="beef cube steak" amount="1.5" unit="pound"/>
    <ingredient name="onion, sliced into thin rings" amount="1"/>
    <ingredient name="green bell pepper, sliced in rings" amount="1"/>
    <ingredient name="Italian seasoned bread crumbs" amount="1" unit="cup"/>
    <ingredient name="grated Parmesan cheese" amount="0.5" unit="cup"/>
    <ingredient name="olive oil" amount="2" unit="tablespoon"/>
    <ingredient name="spaghetti sauce" amount="1" unit="jar"/>
    <ingredient name="shredded mozzarella cheese" amount="0.5" unit="cup"/>
    <ingredient name="angel hair pasta" amount="12" unit="ounce"/>
    <ingredient name="minced garlic" amount="2" unit="teaspoon"/>
    <ingredient name="butter" amount="0.25" unit="cup"/>
    <preparation>
      <step>
        Preheat oven to 350 degrees F (175 degrees C).
      </step>
      <step>
        Cut cube steak into serving size pieces. Coat meat with the bread crumbs
        and parmesan cheese. Heat olive oil in a large frying pan, and saute 1
        teaspoon of the garlic for 3 minutes. Quick fry (brown quickly on both sides)
        meat. Place meat in a casserole baking dish, slightly overlapping edges.
        Place onion rings and peppers on top of meat, and pour marinara sauce
        over all.
      </step>
      <step>
        Bake at 350 degrees F (175 degrees C) for 30 to 45 minutes, depending on
        the thickness of the meat. Sprinkle mozzarella over meat and leave in the
        oven till bubbly.
      </step>
      <step>
        Boil pasta al dente. Drain, and toss in butter and 1 teaspoon garlic. For a
        stronger garlic taste, season with garlic powder. Top with grated parmesan
       and parsley for color. Serve meat and sauce atop a mound of pasta!
      </step>
    </preparation>
    <comment>
      Make the meat ahead of time, and refrigerate over night, the acid in the
      tomato sauce will tenderize the meat even more. If you do this, save the
      mozzarella till the last minute.
    </comment>
    <nutrition calories="1167" fat="23" carbohydrates="45" protein="32"/>
  </recipe>
<recipe>
    <title>Ricotta Pie</title> 
    <ingredient name="filling">
      <ingredient name="ricotta cheese" amount="3" unit="pound"/> 
      <ingredient name="eggs" amount="12"/> 
      <ingredient name="white sugar" amount="2" unit="cup"/> 
      <ingredient name="vanilla extract" amount="2" unit="teaspoon"/> 
      <ingredient name="semisweet chocolate chips" amount="0.25" unit="cup"/> 
      <preparation>
        <step>
          Beat the 12 eggs, 2 cups sugar and vanilla extract together. Stir in
          the ricotta cheese and the chocolate chips. Set aside.
        </step>
      </preparation>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient name="dough">
      <ingredient name="flour" amount="4" unit="cup"/> 
      <ingredient name="baking powder" amount="5" unit="teaspoon"/> 
      <ingredient name="white sugar" amount="1" unit="cup"/> 
      <ingredient name="shortening" amount="0.5" unit="cup"/> 
      <ingredient name="eggs, lightly beaten" amount="4"/> 
      <ingredient name="vanilla extract" amount="1" unit="teaspoon"/> 
      <preparation>
        <step>
          Combine the flour, baking powder, and 1 cup of the sugar together. Cut in the
          shortening and mix until the mixture resembles coarse crumbs. Mix in 4 of
          the eggs and 1 teaspoon of the vanilla. Divide dough into 4 balls and chill (if
          needed).
        </step>
      </preparation>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient name="milk" amount="*"/>
    <preparation>
      <step>
        Preheat oven to 325 degrees F (165 degrees C). Grease two deep dish pie
        plates.
      </step>
      <step>
        Roll out 2 of the balls to fit into the pie pans. Do not make the crust too thick
        as it will expand during cooking and get too thick. Do not flute the edges of
        the dough. Roll out the other 2 balls of dough and cut each into 8 narrow
        strips for the top of the crust. Alternately you can use cookie cutters and
        place the cutouts on the top of the pies.
      </step>
      <step>
        Pour the filling evenly into the pie crusts. Top each pie with 8 narrow strips
        of dough or cookie cut-outs. Brush top of pie with milk for shine. Place foil on
        the edge of crust.
      </step>
      <step>
        Bake at 325 degrees F (165 degrees C) for 20 to 30 minutes then remove
        foil. Continue to bake for another 25 or 30 minutes or until a knife inserted in
        the center comes out clean.
      </step>
    </preparation>
    <nutrition calories="349" fat="18" carbohydrates="64" protein="18"/>
  </recipe>
> </recipes>
```

The code I've made is following

```xml
<result>
    {
        for $x in doc()/recipes/recipe
        order by $x/nutrition[@calories>600]
        return 
            ($x/title) |($x/nutrition[@calories])
    }
</result>
```

The main idea of XQuery expression is to show the title and the calories ordered by calories in `<result>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt doesn't look that bad, apart from that the result XML doesn't look very useful. You might want to rewrap each title and nutrition in a recipe element. Secondly, your order clause is likely to not do much. You write:

```
order by $x/nutrition[@calories>600]
```

But that way you order by the text contents of the nutrition element, which it doesn't have any. You probably meant:

```
order by $x/nutrition[@calories>600]/@calories
```

Or perhaps even better, you want to order numerically on calories:

```
order by $x/nutrition[@calories>600]/@calories/fn:number(.)
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve exactly. So what does the `calories > 600` condition stand for (it does not seem to be of much use in the order by clause, as it will just apply to the ordering condition). I would guess, that you want to filter out all nutrition values with less than 600 calories (your current statement would order everything with more than 600 calories, but the others would still appear in the result).

Also, you did miss to put the `@calories` attribute as the ordering attribute, which I guess is what you want to achieve.

```
<result>
    {
        for $x in doc()/recipes/recipe
        return ($x/title,
          for $n in $x/nutrition[@calories>600]
          order by $n/@calories
          return $n
        )
    }
</result>
```

Comment: the order by only applies to the inner flwor. Good point about calories > 600 though..